# Raspberry Pi Desktop trackpad issue

Tags: hardware, mouse, raspberry-pi-desktop, settings

I hope that this is the right place to ask Raspberry Pi Desktop (https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/raspberry-pi-desktop/) questions.  If not, please feel free to direct me to the right Exchange.

I did the install on a Compaq Mini 110.  The trackpad works for mousing around, but not for scrolling, or tapping.  There are no options, or configuration, available in Settings.  Any ideas how to dig into that type of setting, or are there any known utilities that might address this?

Other than that, everything seems to work really well on it.

Comment: Ehhh... I think its questionable if this is really Pi related, since here is more about the pi hardware. I think you might find better luck in a debian related forum.  Have you installed other flavors of linux on that Compaq before and had full use of the trackpad?

Comment: As a general linux note,  many "extra" features of keyboards/mice dont work with linux out of the box(or at least not with more stripped down OS's)

Comment: Raspberry Pi Desktop is just a Debian OS with a Raspberry look and feel. Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions.